# Using Storyboards Segues

Tags: ios, memory-management, uistoryboard

I have a question about how I use segues with Storyboard in Xcode.
I have an application with 3 views, and I would load them with animation modal "Cross Dissolve".

Every time I load a new view without dismiss the current one, it still occupying memory?
I'm realizing that after changing multiple views my APP becomes slow.

If yes, how is the right way to change views in sequence?

[image]

Comment: what does "change views in sequence" mean? Also with this work flow above you are not going "Back to 1" you are actually creating a NEW ViewController.

Comment: @Firo yeah thats the point. I think Im creating a lot of NewControllers and having memory loss by creating multiple modals. Change Views in Sequence: First View -> Second View -> Third View -> First View (But Using `Cross Dissolve` animation.)

Answer (score 1):

When you go back from 3 to 1 you should use an unwind segue. That will cause 3 and 2 to be deallocated (if you're not keeping a strong pointer to them), and you will actually go back to the same instance of 1 (rather than creating a new one). In general, you should not go backwards using a segue other than an unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying the "back to 1" segue in the storyboard, you may want to instantiate it in code using the method `-initWithIdentifier:source:destination:`. That'll permit you to specify the destination as your first view controller instead of creating a new view controller to transition to.

In fact, you should probably specify all the segues between these view controllers programmatically if you don't want to instantiate new copies with each switch.